# skipping 2 lines with list comprehnsion

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to utilise list comprehension for sorting data from a very large file. The file structure is like so:

```
THING
info1
info2
info3
THING
info1
info2
info3
```

... and so on.

Basically trying to collect all info1 into a list and all info2 into another list. I have a previous script which does this, but it's slow. I'm also trying to make it object oriented so I can use the data more efficiently.

Old script:

```
info1_data = []
info2_data = []
with open(myfile) as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.search('THING',line):
            line=next(f)
            info1_data.append(line)
            line=next(f)
            info2_data.append(line)
```

New script:

```
def __init__(self, file):
    self.file = file

def sort_info1(self):
    with self.file as f:
        info1_data = [next(f) for line in f if re.search('THING',line)]
    return info1_data

def sort_info2(self):
    with self.file as f:
        info2_data = [next(f).next(f) for line in f if re.search('THING',line)]
    return info2_data
```

The new script works for getting info1_data as a list. However, to get info2_data I can't find anything for skipping 2 lines using this method. I guessed at `next(f).next(f)`. It runs but doesn't produce anything.

Is this possible?

Many thanks.

Following help from Moses I've this solution. The islice is very confusing though and I don't fully understand it, even after reading the python.docs. Does the iterable get the data (i.e., info1 or info2) or do the start, stop and step dictate what data is extracted?

islice(iterable, start, stop[, step])

```
from itertools import islice
import re

class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file

    def search(self, word, i):
        self.file.seek(0) # seek to start of file
        for line in self.file:
            if re.search(word, line) and i == 0:
                line = next(self.file)
                yield line
            elif re.search(word, line) and i == 1:
                line = next(self.file)
                line = next(self.file)
                yield line

    def sort_info1(self):
        return list(islice(self.search('THING',0), 0, None, 2))

    def sort_info2(self):
        return list(islice(self.search('THING',1), 2, None, 2))


info1 = SomeClass(open("test.dat")).sort_info1()
info2 = SomeClass(open("test.dat")).sort_info2()
```

Comment: write you own `next` function that takes the number of lines to skip as a second argument with a default of 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should the `seek` the file back to the start in order to repeat the search from the beginning of the file. Also, you could use a generator function to decouple the search operation from the production of the data. Then use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to step over lines:

```
from itertools import islice

class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file

    def search(self, word):
        self.file.seek(0) # seek to start of file
        for line in self.file:
            if re.search(word, line):
                # yield next two lines
                yield next(self.file)
                yield next(self.file)

    def sort_info1(self):
        return list(islice(self.search('THING'), 0, None, 2))

    def sort_info2(self):
        return list(islice(self.search('THING'), 1, None, 2))
```

However instead of passing the file, I'll suggest you pass the path to the file instead so the file can be **closed** after each use, to avoid holding up resources when they are not (or not yet) needed.

Comment: thanks! I'm new to islice... I've incorporated this into my script but it just returns the search word 'THING' as a list instead of info1 or info2 as lists. I've looked through the python docs but still don't quite follow it.

Comment: @matman9 Are you yielding the right items from the generator function?

Comment: @matman9 It should. Start from `0`, till the end, stepping 2 lines at a time.

Comment: so the search function finds the 'THING' and yields the line that its on, and the sort_info1() function returns a list from iterating from the yielded line stepping every 2 lines? sorry, I'm just trying to break it down so I can follow what it's doing.

Comment: I've tried changing the islice input but it keeps giving me the same output. you mentioned yielding the right items, what does this mean? from finding 'THING' I need to then get the next line (info1), and line after that (info2), does the islice not do this? thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151279/discussion-between-matman9-and-moses-koledoye).

Comment: @matman9 I've updated the answer. I should have yielded the next two lines after the line instead of yielding line itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
def sort_info2(self):
    with self.file as f:
        info2_data = [(next(f),next(f))[1] for line in f if re.search('THING',line)]
    return info2_data
```

But it looks a little weird way!